# SPSS Administrator failed to connect to IBM SPSS Modeler Server

Tags: server, spss, administration, spss-modeler

Recently i have installed IBM SPSS Modeler Server 17.1 to RHEL OS.The SPSS Modeler Server is installed under a **non-root user**. 
I have tried to configure the options.cfg file:-

1) Change default port to 8111:- **port_number, 8111**

2) Enable: **administrators, "*"** (I know it is not secure, will update the setting after issue solved)

3) Add in parameters: **authentication_methods, "pasw_modeler"**

4) Use PWUtil to create user:- **bin/pwutil   >> config/passwords.cfg**

Next, i tried to login using SPSS Administartion Console (from my laptop). However, it failed to login with the crendential that i created previously.

But from server log, i can see the statement as below:

```
2016-04-11 15:31:40,435    18526 0x7f0da0b93760 INFO  SDLServerApp AEQMC0075I: Accepted connection from ::ffff:xx.xx.xx.xxx.:60462

2016-04-11 15:31:40,700    19451 0x7f0da0b93760 INFO  SDLSessionServer AEQMC0034I: Login succeeded for user: <user>
```

Any hints or suggestions to troubleshoot the issue?

================< Update >=====================

I have double checked with all version i used for SPSS Server, Client and Administration, and are similar (17.0).

Telnet checking is okay as well.

I tried using SPSS Batch in remote server (where SPSS Server is installed), i managed to connect and create session.

I have also applied fixed patch 1 for SPSS Server and SPSS Batch.

Then, i tried to install SPSS Server under root user. Set **administrators, "*"** and **port_number, 8111**. Same issue happened again, the log showed Login Succeed, but client side failed to connect

Any help are very much appreciated.

===========< Update 2 >========================

Actually i have installed the SPSS Server to a local desktop, and i managed to connect to the server with same settings after disabled iptables firewall.

So, are there anything else required to enabled in firewall level? Other than the 3 ports (port_number, cop_port_number, as_port) that we configured in options.cfg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue myself. :) Seem like SPSS Server will use random port when connecting with client or administration tools. Due to the infra design here, only a few of ports have been enabled. Thus, to overcome the issue, i have setup the minimum and maximum port range in the options.cfg.

```
min_server_port, <min>
max_server_port, <max>
```